# Display separate camera photo on each UIImageView using imagePicker

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I have two camera upload buttons, each with a seperate UIImageView next to it. I want the left upload to place the photo taken in the left UIImageView, and the right upload to place the photo in the right UIImageView.
[image: See Image]

The issue is that I can't differentiate between each image, so the same image displays on both UIImageViews.

```
@IBOutlet var imageTake: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var imageTake2: UIImageView!

var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController!

func takePhoto() {
    imagePicker =  UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.delegate = self as UIImagePickerControllerDelegate & UINavigationControllerDelegate
    imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
    present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func uploadButton(_ sender: Any) {
takePhoto()
}


@IBAction func uploadButton2(_ sender: Any) {
takePhoto()
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    imageTake.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    imageTake2.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage

}
```

I believe my issue is in this line where it sets both UIImageViews to `info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]` which I think is wrong, but I don't know how to make that variable hold each photo individually.

Any help would be very appreciated

Comment: Do not repeat your code. Have a common `takePhone` method that you call from both button handlers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not going to take two pictures simultaneously. So just use an instance property `currentButton`. In your `uploadButton` method(s), set `currentButton` to the `sender` — the button. In `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`, look at `currentButton` to see which button it is. You know which button it is, so you know which image view to use. It will help if you give your buttons and image views a `tag` that matches, so you know instantly which image view goes with which button.

So assume that button 1 has tag `1` and image view 1 has tag `11`. And button 2 has tag `2` and image view 2 has tag `12`. Then in `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`, you pull out `currentButton`, get its `tag`, add 10, do a `viewWithTag` to find that image view, and plunk the image into that.

Comment: I was writing the exact same answer! That's exactly what I'd do. @danboy, one more thing (not necessary but helpful) consider changing the `sender` from `Any` to `UIButton`.

Comment: It should be emphasized, however, that this is not really the "right" way. Preserving state during an asynchronous procedure is skanky. The right thing to do is to have two different `delegate` helper objects, each associated with one button-image view pair. But that's left as an exercise for the reader. :)

Comment: Thanks for the help @matt. I don't quite understand how that would translate into code and I am pretty new with swift so I will try and look into your solution